# ulimit -t under ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

I am running Ubuntu Linux (2.6.28-11-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 01:57:59 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux) and it seems that the command "ulimit -t" does not work properly. I ran:

ulimit -t 1; myprogram

where 'myprogram' is an endless loop. I expected the program to be interrupted after 1 second, but it did not stop. I tried the same thing on a Linux Fedora installation and it worked as expected.

Is there some configuration that has to be set for it to work properly?

-- tsf

Answer (score 17):

As [Tsf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115211/tsf) pointed out, the problem is due to a [bug in kernel 2.6.28](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jaunty/%2Bsource/linux/%2Bbug/361508). 
I leave my original answer, because I think it could be helpful anyway.

From the ulimit manpage

> `-t   The maximum amount of cpu time`
>   `in seconds.`

What counts in respect to ulimit is only **CPU time**.
Try to start your program like this:

```
time myprogram
```

That will show you how much CPU time it really uses.

My suspicion is that your endless loop contains `sleep()`
and sleep time does not contribute to the CPU time of the process.

This gets killed after one second:

```
me@host:~$ bash
me@host:~$ ulimit -t 1; for (( i=1; 1; i++ )); do a=1; done
Killed
```

This seems to run forever (but of course does not):

```
me@host:~$ bash
me@host:~$ ulimit -t 1; for (( i=1; 1; i++ )); do sleep 1; done
```

Measure CPU time like this...

```
me@host:~$  time for (( i=1; i<5; i++ )); do sleep 1; done
```

...and 5 seconds later...

```
real        0m4.008s
user        0m0.000s
sys         0m0.012s
```

...only 12 ms CPU time used.

I tried it on ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope (9.04)

```
Linux host 2.6.28-11-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP 
Fri Apr 17 01:57:59 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: No I don't have any sleep in my program. Notice that it works as expected under Fedora, so that it looks like a configuration problem on my Ubuntu.

Comment: I posted the same question under a different topic and it was answered by directing me to:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jaunty/%2Bsource/linux/%2Bbug/361508

That explains the problem!

Comment: Thanks, I added your hint at the top of my answer.
I think it is better if people see the kernel bug first.