# how do I limit the running time of a process using ulimit?

Tags: linux, bash, ulimit

I am trying to use `ulimit`, a feature of the bash shell, to limit the time that a program is allowed to run.  For example, I tried this:

```
 $   ( ulimit -t 1; ./a.out )
```

But it does not work.  it lets the `./a.out` program run until it stops (5 seconds).
Anybody know how to do this?  By the way, I experimented with including a `-H`
on the `ulimit` command line, but it just gives this error:

```
bash: ulimit: cpu time: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is a difference between CPU time (which is what you specify with `ulimit -t`) and actual run time. You can see how much CPU time your program used by running `time ./a.out`. `time` reports real elapsed time, user CPU time, and system CPU time.

Comment: I'm interested in CPU time. Can you shed any light on how to do what I want?

Comment: Did you try `( ulimit -t 1; time ./a.out )` to verify that your program is really exceeding one second of CPU time?

Comment: yes, the result of "time ./a.out" is over 5 seconds of "user" time and "real" time.

Answer (score 9):

`ulimit` cannot limit program run time, only CPU time. If you have [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), you can use the [timeout](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) command instead:

```
timeout 1s ./a.out
```

This will `kill` your program after one second. You can specify the signal to send using `-s` or `--signal`, e.g.

```
timeout --signal=HUP 1s ./a.out
```

Comment: I don't have the "timeout" function.  By the way, what I did above does work on my ubuntu machine with a newer operating system.  So I am on the right track, and I think what I am doing ought to work.  The system I have is 2.6.28.4-002-STD64

Comment: Okay, there's a bug in this kernel.  I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978317/ulimit-t-under-ubuntu?rq=1).

It points out that what I want to do does not work in 2.6.28.

Comment: @user2839463 Please post that as a separate answer so people who land on this page in the future can find it more easily.